# C# Syntax SQL Error Select ... Insert

Tags: c#, sql

> "The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than
>   the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns."

I have a question is this right? The construction of my codes?

```
private void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you done adding your items?","Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Conn = k.getConn();
                Conn.Open();
                str = "INSERT INTO Items (itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor , qty) SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor FROM Purchase";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str, Conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cmd.Dispose();
                Conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added to your CART" ,"Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else if (res == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
    }`
```

And i want to transfer that in the database named Items

Comment: `Insert` column list has **four** columns and `Select` column list **three** columns.

Comment: And what is the purpose of the call to ExecuteReader after the ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Items (itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor , qty) SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor, qty FROM Purchase`

Comment: you need key word VALUES instead of SELECT

Comment: @ChenChi No no no, definitely `SELECT` is the easier and correct way here

Comment: @Prdp thank you for reminding me that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query below:

```
str = "INSERT INTO Items (itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor , qty) SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor FROM Purchase";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str, Conn);
```

you must pass exactly four column names in the select query so that the clumn list matches the columns list of insert query. If you donot want to fetch data for quantity column, then remove it from the INSERT query.

You can also set a default value for the quantity column in your database to ensure that it gets a default integral value instead of NULL.
Secondaly, there is no need to use the following statement after ExecuteNonQuery():

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

because you are not doin anything with the data that may be conming to dr.
Instead, if you are trying to get the number of rows affected by the insert query, you can use the following code:

```
int cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and then show the value of this variable where ever you want, may be in a label.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See, ExecuteReader returns a resultset containing data fetched by select statement. It is strictly used for fetching records. Please tell me the purpose of using ExecuteReader in your code so that I can guide you in a better way.

Comment: It really WORKS thanks ! and one last question what will I do to

Comment: I need your help.. is this right? @Shobit Gupta
INSERT INTO Items(itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor, qty , itemPrice) SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor, qty ," + tb1.Text " + "

Comment: Hi. This is not the right implementation. In the list of columns, you need to put up the names of columns that exist in the database and not the data from textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

In the query for `insert` there are 4 columns

```
INSERT INTO Items (itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor , qty)
```

in the `select` there are only 3 columns

```
 SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor FROM Purchase
```

It should be as follows

```
INSERT INTO Items (itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor , qty)
SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor,qty FROM Purchase
```

Comment: What if i add something like this , please check if this is right or wrong
INSERT INTO Items(itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor, qty , itemPrice)
SELECT itemCode, itemBrand, itemColor, qty ," + tb1.Text " + " @Berkay

Comment: @AllemMontinola I am not owner of the solution, I just corrected the format.